# spread doesn't work with null

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

ES6 spread won't work this way

```
I have this.state = { sortedKey: null } in my constructor and I do

this.setState({
sortedKey: [...this.state.sortedKey, 'something']
})
```

I got error of `Cannot convert undefined or null to object`?

Comment: spread only works on objects.. if you default to null,  it causes an error. change it to `{ sortedKey: {} }`

Comment: And what's your question? According to the spec, thrown an error is the expected behavior: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-getiterator .

Comment: @Jalil: that will also throw an error. Objects are not iterable.

Comment: @FelixKling: yeah, I forgot. I was thinking with babel in mind.

Comment: what about this.state = { "sortedKey": [ ] } in constructor

Comment: @Jalil: I could be wrong but even with the property spread feature  it wouldn't make sense. What would the result of spreading an *object* into an *array* be?

Comment: it will cause an error. ^_^

Comment: Please show the desired input and the desired output.  We can't tell what you expect to end up with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var state = { "sortedKey": [] };

var newState = {"sortedKey": [...state.sortedKey, 'something']};

console.log(newState)
```